# Wordpress plugin doesn't load jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm building a FAQ plugin for my website in Wordpress but the jQuery doesn't load. I had the same problem when I tried to hide a submit button on a contact form earlier and had to hide it with CSS. Should also say i'm new to jQuery and it's possible I have missed something. Thanks!

PHP:

```
    wp_register_script( 'javascript', plugins_url('js/javascript.js',__FILE__ ));
    wp_enqueue_script('javascript');

echo '<div class="qaleft">' . '<div class="toggle">' . '<h3>' . $post_titles . '</h3>' . '<div class="toggle-info">' . '<p>' . $post_content . '</p>' . '</div>' . '</div>' . '</div>';
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
 $('.toggle h3').on('click', function(e){
    var answer = $(this).next('.toggle-info');

    if(!$(answer).is(":visible")) {
      $(this).parent().addClass('open');
    } else {
      $(this).parent().removeClass('open');
    }
    $(answer).slideToggle(300);
  });
});
```

Comment: Did you rename your jQuery library file to javascript.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Wordpress jQuery uses no conflict mode, so you cannot use the dollar sign as you are attempting.

To fix use the full name and pass the dollar as a parameter:

```
jQuery(function($){
 //from here on you can use $ as a placeholder to jQuery, as you normally do
 $('.toggle h3').on('click', function(e){
    var answer = $(this).next('.toggle-info');

    if(!$(answer).is(":visible")) {
      $(this).parent().addClass('open');
    } else {
      $(this).parent().removeClass('open');
    }
    $(answer).slideToggle(300);
  });
});
```

Also, make sure jquery is loaded by including it in the dependancy argument when you register your custom script:

```
wp_register_script( 'javascript', plugins_url('js/javascript.js',__FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ));
```